# Syntax for JSON 'payload' in Facebook FB.api post

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to add users to a `Custom Audience` in Facebook, and I believe I have bungled the `payload` piece of the request below.

The error returned is:

```
(#100) Missing required parameter: payload
```

For reference, I'm generating the hash using `Crypto-JS`.  Here's the code I tried:

```
var payload = { "payload": [{ "schema": "EMAIL_SHA256", "data": [hash] }]};

FB.api('/000000000/users', 'post', payload, function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    alert("This worked");
                } else {
                    alert(response.error.message);
                }});
```

The FB.api documentation shows that it expects 'payload' as a JSON object (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-targeting/v2.3#add). I just haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax yet.  The example in the Facebook API documentation shows the following:

```
payload = {"schema":"EMAIL_SHA256","data":["HASH", "HASH", "HASH" ]}
```

Here's what I have so far (not working):

```
var payload = { "payload": [{ "schema": "EMAIL_SHA256", "data": [hash] }]};
```

Can anyone assist with the syntax?  I've found plenty of examples of JSON objects and arrays, but I haven't seen anything that matches this format:

```
payload = {"schema":"EMAIL_SHA256","data":["HASH", "HASH", "HASH" ]}
```

Comment: Why would you use `parameter = value` when passing parameters to a function?

Comment: You need to pass an object, that contains `payload` as a _property_. (Not sure if a pure JS object will be automatically converted by `FB.api`, or if you have to pass the value as a JSON-encoded string value already.)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It looks like FB.api expects 'payload' as a JSON object (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-targeting/v2.3#add).  I just haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax yet.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of any other JS/JSON novices, I finally figured it out after more experimentation:

```
 var payload = { "payload": { "schema": "EMAIL_SHA256", "data": [hash] } };
```